# How to install the .Net AOT compiler so it can be called from the command line without using the dotnet command

Tags: c#, .net, operating-system, native-aot

I'm writing a baremetal OS kernel in C# and I would like to execute the .Net AOT compiler from the command line without using the dotnet command, also avoiding the use of a csproj file.

On searching my file system, I notice a copy of the ILC, the Native AOT compiler, stored in the following location on my local machine: `C:\Users\frank\.nuget\packages\runtime.win-x64.microsoft.dotnet.ilcompiler\7.0.14"\tools`

I can actually call it successfully, `ilc <args>`, and it does perform the ahead of time compilation.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how it got there and I need a reliable way to setup a fresh build environment.

How can I deterministically install, and then run, the .Net AOT compiler?  (either .Net version 7 or 8 is fine).

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe I can `dotnet add package Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler --version 7.0.14`

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use the dotnet command?

Comment: @PMF - Because in the fullness of time, I intend to use BFlat to compile it direct to machine code, avoiding installing the .Net SDK or .Net runtime, see: https://github.com/bflattened/bflat

Comment: Run dotnet publish with /bl   .  That will give you a binlog which you can dig into to see the various commands that are run which you can replicate manually?